# Assets routing in Sub-Projects

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to have an admin sub project with the play-framework. In the admin call `http://localhost:9000/admin/index` I can't reach the admin views, there is a problem with the assets. Can't figure out what's wrong:

```scala
val appDependencies = Seq(
// Add your project dependencies here,
javaCore,
javaJdbc,
javaEbean)

  // admin module
  val admin = play.Project(appName + "-admin", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("modules/admin"))

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path = file(".")).settings( 
  // Add your own project settings here      
  ).dependsOn(admin).aggregate(admin)
```

Project structure looks like this:

```
.
|-app
|---controllers
|---views
|-conf
|-logs
|-modules
|---admin
|-----app
|-------controllers
|---------admin
|-------views
|---------admin
|-----conf
|-----public
|-----test
|-project
|-public
|---images
|---javascripts
|---stylesheets
|-test
```

conf/routes

```
    GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

    ->  /admin admin.Routes

    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

/modules/admin/conf/admin.routes

```
    GET     /index                           controllers.admin.Application.index()

    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    #GET     /assets/*file               controllers.admin.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Here in `admin.routes` it doesn't work with this: `GET /assets/*file controllers.admin.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `GET /assets/*file controllers.admin.Assets.at(path="/public", file)` in admin is not necessary neither is `/assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)` in admin.

But the views need to be called different. e.g. viewsadmin (views/admin/ doesn't work)